# Server in Client's computer to create a TCP persistent link

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to create a Java server in the client's browser to collect and manage communication
and update the displayed material in the client browser and receive the Get Push Post statements and then communicate through a long life persistent link for security reasons.

I know some universities have started working on this type of service 
But i would prefer to do this from another approach.

What services/plugins are there that can help me in this field.

Its taken me a long time just to get to this point to even know what I'm asking for
But now I'm hearing I just need the tools and implementation of them.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably known as COMET, and can be done purely in JavaScript, without requiring a Java applet: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))  The advantage being that it could be implemented on a mobile device/tablet as well.

There are a number of libraries that will help you accomplish this depending on your programming environment.  I tend to work in JSF, and so I favor tools for that environment, (IceFaces, RichFaces, PrimeFaces) but your choice of tools will depend on your specific application environment, which you haven't provided much detail about.

Comment: I want to make my own that it only knows to connect to a static IP. And I have some security features of my own to add. I'm thinking of portable devices that may lose the connection for a temporary time and yet hold the page open. This is a good start.

Comment: Many COMET libraries have compensation mechanisms for when the connection drops out and comes back.  The real advantage of using a COMET type connection is that you know when the client is present (because the TCP connection will timeout otherwise), there's no firewall mitigation necessary aside from sending a keep alive every few (10-30) seconds, and it works with most any browser/platform, whether desktop or mobile.  If you write a client side application in Java, you eliminate LOTS of potential clients, including anything iOS, and most android devices.

Comment: Hay if I have a java server running as a local server its should run on anything. Thats the direction I need. Commit needs activex to run on MS explorer and thats dubble standards. And I cannot put my securty system in that.

Comment: Comet does not need anything more than Javascript, and as I mentioned before, Java does not work on all platforms, in particular iOS, not to mention that not everyone has it installed.  Javascript by comparison is universal, and why I recommend Comet over other strategies.  If you're finding someone saying it needs ActiveX, you're being fed a line, and should ignore it.  Comet is typically implemented in pure Javascript, and is a strategy, not a product. Also, your server should maintain security NOT the client. Any other method is just begging to be hacked.